# Shell variable pipeline jenkins bash

Tags: shell, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, var

I have a pipeline that open a ssh connection on target and then I need to run some command.

```
...
sh'''ssh -T '''+server''' << EOF
ls -la
var=$(grep 'test' /etc/passwd | awk -F'' '{print $2}'
echo $var
EOF
'''
```

var is always empty...

Someone has an idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Are you sure a word named `test` exists in /etc/passwd file. Please ensure this using `cat /etc/passwd`

Comment: And even if you found `test`, the `awk -F''` will wipe any output. Did you test it before on the target system, before building the complex script?